# what is wrong? gridviev display incorrectly

Tags: android, gridview

**Grid**

```
 <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewProdact_2"
        style="@style/scroll_bar_green"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/controller"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

    </GridView>
```

**item grid**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/item_grid"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/item_grid"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/image_company" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and shows this

[image]

whot is wrong?

Comment: i thnk the problem with images. i am not sure but once check the images.

Comment: check with Hierarchy Viewer

Answer (score 1):

USE like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" > 

</GridView>
```

with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, i found my problem When i change orientation screen my grigView worded incorrectly